# PHPUnit Autoload.php does not exist

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm on a mac and when I type which phpunit it directs me to where phpunit is installed.
It only contains PHPUnit as unix executable.

However, CakePHP is looking for PHPUnit/Autoload.php which does not exist

My PHPUnit version is 4.0.11

Comment: Is the folder of PHP Unit in your (include) path?